# Intellij start error

Tags: intellij-idea

I installed a python plugin in Intellij and then on restart I am getting following error dialog when starting Intellij IDE.

`java.lang.AssertionError: Unexpected node Pythonid; nodes=[org.jetbrains.settingsRepository, org.jetbrains.plugins.yaml, org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal, org.jetbrains.plugins.ruby, org.jetbrains.plugins.javaFX, org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle, org.jetbrains.kotlin, org.jetbrains.java.decompiler, org.jetbrains.idea.maven.ext, org.jetbrains.idea.maven, org.jetbrains.android, org.intellij.intelliLang, org.intellij.groovy, org.editorconfig.editorconfigjetbrains, com.jetbrains.restWebServices, com.jetbrains.restClient, com.jetbrains.plugins.asp, com.intellij.ui-designer-new, com.intellij.spring.webflow, com.intellij.spring.mvc, com.intellij.spring, com.intellij.properties, com.intellij.plugins.html.instantEditing, com.intellij.persistence, com.intellij.modules.xml, com.intellij.modules.xdebugger, com.intellij.modules.vcs, com.intellij.modules.ultimate, com.intellij.modules.sql, com.intellij.modules.ruby, com.intellij.modules.remoteServers, com.intellij.modules.python, com.intellij.modules.platform, com.intellij.modules.lang, com.intellij.modules.json, com.intellij.modules.java, com.intellij.modules.database, com.intellij.modules.all, com.intellij.jsp, com.intellij.jsf, com.intellij.javaee, com.intellij.java-i18n, com.intellij.hibernate, com.intellij.guice, com.intellij.freemarker, com.intellij.diagram, com.intellij.database, com.intellij.css, com.intellij.copyright, com.intellij.cdi, com.intellij.aspectj, com.intellij.aop, com.intellij, ZKM, W3Validators, Tomcat, TestNG-J, Refactor-X, QuirksMode, JavaScriptDebugger, JavaScript, Java EE: Web Services (JAX-WS),` JUnit, JSIntentionPowerPack, J2ME, HtmlTools, DevKit, AntSupport]
    at com.intellij.util.graph.GraphGenerator.buildOuts(GraphGenerator.java:55)
    at com.intellij.util.graph.GraphGenerator.(GraphGenerator.java:36)
    at com.intellij.util.graph.GraphGenerator.create(GraphGenerator.java:40)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.c(PluginManagerCore.java:622)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.b(PluginManagerCore.java:1167)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.a(PluginManagerCore.java:1334)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.getPlugins(PluginManagerCore.java:105)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.a(ComponentManagerImpl.java:328)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:455)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:447)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:60)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:361)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a solution. Just removed the python plugin directory under `C:\Users\<account name>\.IntelliJIdea15\config\plugins`.